# Cannot update params when use warden.authenticate in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, warden

I have upgrade my rails from 3.2.8 to rails 4, also devise is upgrade from 2.1.2 to 3.5.6 and warden from 1.2.3 to 1.2.6.
I found an issue that I don't know what it should belongs to devise or warden.

Before I call

```
resource = warden.authenticate(:scope => resource_name, :recall =>"#{controller_path}#new")
```

I update params value like below:

```
params[:admin] = Hash.new 
params[:admin][:email] = params[:email] 
params[:admin][:password] = params[:password]
```

But when I print params in proxy.rb, the function def authenticate(*args)
the params is still the original, there are no any admin in it.

> The issue is not happened when I use the old system.

Here is my part of code and logs:
controllers.rb

```
params[:admin] = Hash.new
params[:admin][:email] = params[:email]
params[:admin][:password] = params[:password]
params[:password] = '11111111111111'
# authenticate with warden
p '===================================='
p params
p warden
resource = warden.authenticate(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
p params
p '===================================='
```

proxy.rb

```
def authenticate(*args)
  p 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss'
  p params
  params[:password] = '111111111'
  p params
  p 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss'
  user, _opts = _perform_authentication(*args)
  user
end
```

logs:

```
"===================================="
{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"11111111111111", "controller"=>"admin_sessions", "action"=>"create", "version"=>"v1", "format"=>"json", "admin"=>{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"xxxxxxxx"}}
Warden::Proxy:70145506030260 @config={:default_scope=>:admin, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:admin=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#Devise::Delegator:0x007f980f873e18}
"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"xxxxxxxx", "controller"=>"admin_sessions", "action"=>"create", "version"=>"v1", "format"=>"json"}
{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"111111111", "controller"=>"admin_sessions", "action"=>"create", "version"=>"v1", "format"=>"json"}
"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"111111111", "controller"=>"admin_sessions", "action"=>"create", "version"=>"v1", "format"=>"json"}
"sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"11111111111111", "controller"=>"admin_sessions", "action"=>"create", "version"=>"v1", "format"=>"json", "admin"=>{"email"=>"syter@xxxx.com", "password"=>"xxxxxxxx"}}
"===================================="
```

It seems there are two params, one is in controller, one is in warden.

Is there any configuration or any other things I missed?

Hope ur answers,
Thank u.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't see this question when I asked and answered something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512141/208769

Annoyingly, it seems that the `params` you see in the controller is a clone of the `params` that rack maintains, rather than a reference to it. And because warden intercepts the request in a middleware layer, it maintains its link to the request params, and knows nothing about the controller's clone.

In short, if you want to modify params and have warden see your modifications, you need to modify `request.params`